# Can anyone give me some tips for Super Street Figher 4 on 3DS?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition

No matter which character I pick (Arcade Mode), I can never get past the 3rd challenger. I feel like I must be missing some major element that is causing me to just always lose. I block, I attack, I use combos... maybe I just need practice but, this is either very unbalanced or I just suck.

Is there some strategy, techniques, secrets, good approach, mindset? ANYTHING you can share that might help? It's really awesome but the fun fades quickly if I can't progress.

Comment: Is this your first Street Fighter game? It might be helpful to make note of your experience with SF.

Comment: I have 4 on Steam but never got far either. Only played the original a few times in the arcade.

Comment: if you post your windows live id here, we can spar a few times next time I'm online

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not played SSF4 on the 3DS, but I can provide some general Street Fighter 4 tips:

1. Start by sticking to a single character and becoming familiar with all their attack moves and supers.  It doesn't matter what 'tier' your chosen character is, familiarity is more important.  Learn the range of the normal attacks, specials, and ultras.  Test this out with all three power levels (jab, medium, and fierce).
2. Be defensive.  Typically, the CPU is pretty bad at being defensive, even going up against the most difficult level CPU, you can typically force them to commit into an attack or become airborne, leaving them wide open for a counter.
3. Do not overuse special moves.  Quick jabs and pokes can often be very effective, and may knock characters out of their special attack (crouch + jab vs blanka's roll, for instance).
4. The air is not your friend.  Do not over jump in an attempt to reach the opponent, when you are in the air you cannot block and can easily be hit.
5. Your super bar is not just for supers.  Often, a charged up special (by hitting 2 out of the 3 punch or kick buttons to perform the move), will allow you to completely overpower the opponent's special move.  Certain characters, such as Blanka's roll, will allow him to completely blow through a hadouken.
6. Don't forget that you can throw.  If the enemy is right next to you, throw them for some damage.
7. Learn your counters, certain special moves are great counters for anyone who's being overly aggressive.  For instance, the shoruyken is great move to pull off just as you are getting up if you know the enemy is about to perform an attack.
8. As you become more familiar with your character, you can start learning the combo moves that they have.  These lead very well from normal jabs and pokes that you perform.  For instance, if your jab just happens to hit them when they are not blocking, you can follow up with a second jab and then a special if you time it right.  Long combo chains will come as second nature to you over time as you become more familiar with your character.
9. Have fun, if you can't win, consider turning down the difficulty level, turn it back up as you become more skilled.

Most of these tips will let you master fighting the computer (SF4 versus is another matter ;).

Comment: +1 for recommending having fun. There's no sense on playing if there's no fun in the game.

Answer (score 3):

Advice for *any* Street Fighter game, not specific to Super Street fighter 3D:

*Block*. You only lose a round if your adversary deals damage to you, so every loss is due to a breach on your defense.

Don't jump very often. Jumps have predefined arcs and you can't block during a jump. So, it's easy for your adversary to predict where you'll be during a jump and attack for free.

Every attack takes some time to land. If your adversary uses a faster attack before your attack lands, you will take damage.

If you miss an attack, there is some time for the recovery. If your opponent attacks you during this period, you can't react.

So, the safest way to play is to stay on the defensive and attack with quick moves, punishing your opponent when they make a mistake.

Supposing you're playing Ken vs Guile. A Shoryuken is a good anti-air move. But if you misjudge the distance, it will whiff, and it has a huge recovery time, on which Guile may hit you with an Ultra or another dangerous move. So, you could consider using a High Kick or a crouching High Punch, since those moves are faster (but not completely safe if you miss either).

Long story short: defense is safer than offense, at least before you learn how to attack well. Block your opponent's attacks and punish them on their mistakes. And *never* jump if Guile is crouching.

Answer (score 0):

yx_'s tips are spot on. The CPU is very cheap and will react to things that no human possibly could! Possibly the most important is to avoid jumping. Once the CPU ramps up to a certain difficulty, it will punish your jump-in every single time.

If you simply want to get through Arcade Mode and don't mind being "cheap" to the CPU in return, there are some things that the CPU simply can't deal with. One example is Zangief. The computer can't play against him well. Place ultra, super, 360 piledriver, and lariat on the touchpad buttons -- all of these moves are extremely effective against the computer because it can't punish or avoid them properly.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are great but I think they leave out one very important point, start on very easy. I'm not sure from your post if you are starting there or starting on medium (the default). Everyone is a beginner at some point so don't feel bad for starting out at the lower difficulty. I'd share my friend code so we could play sometime but im not sure if board rules restrict that sort of thing, I'm pretty decent but if you need a sparing partner send me a private message. That goes for anyone reading this that is looking for a SSF4 3D match. :D

Comment: Believe it or not, this was actually hindering me. I was playing on Medium mode. The first 2-3 guys would be cake but then suddenly it would be difficult. So instead I increased it to Hard mode. Because I was up against a challenge and an aggressive opponent right off the bat, it allowed me to actually know what I am going up against for later down the road. I wasn't practicing against weaklings and then trying to fight strong ones, I was practicing against strong ones the whole time. It was a surprising revelation.

Comment: I actually believe you. Hah, If you stick in the "kiddie pool" too long you will never know how to swim. To progress tho you most definitely need to know when it's no longer a challenge and when to step up into the big boy pants. But starting out on a hard difficulty can sometimes turn a potential player into a person looking to trade in a game. Everyone has there own style, just thought I would put in my thoughts :D